# Golang,MongoDB, Having issues using $in to find all elements with one string in there array property

Tags: mongodb, go

I am trying to find all users in a MongoDB collection that contains a  username string in the friends array. I am using Golang with the mgo driver.

```
   type User struct {
    ...
        Friends        []string    `json: friends bson:"friends,omitempty"` 
    ...
    }

    ...
    // username is a string
    arr := []string{username}

    err := c.Find(bson.M{"friends": {"$in": arr}}).All(&users)
    ...
```

I get this error:
http: panic serving [::1]:56358: assignment to entry in nil map

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are using "$in" wrong. You aren't initialising inner map. You are supposed to use it like this:

```
err := c.Find(bson.M{"friends": bson.M{"$in": arr}}).All(&users)
```

Comment: I tried that and now I get.  http: panic serving [::1]:59541: assignment to entry in nil map

Comment: Never mind the issue was down the line in the HTTP response. You are correct that resolved the issue. Thank you for the help!

Comment: thanks, its working for me.

Comment: thanks, bson.M is much simpler to work than bson.D and bson.E